# Simulating HTTP Server Responses issue while connecting

Tags: http, web, server, protocols

I am working on a practical exercise related to HTTP and I need some guidance. The exercise involves simulating HTTP server responses from the command line using cat. Here are the specific tasks I'm trying to accomplish:

Exercise 1 – Question 1.1:
I need to prepare an HTTP response where:

```
I return a status code indicating that the request has been executed without errors.
I use the mode where the connection is closed after the request.
I use the content of simple.html for the resource flow.
```

I need to execute the command `cat rep_http simple.html | nc -l 8080 -q 0`

So far I've create a simple webpage as well as rep_http contents of which:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: close
```

However whenever I execute the command above, as soon as I connect to http://localhost:8080, he connection is immediately closed and no contents appear neither on webpage nor console.

Could someone guide me through the steps for resolving these problems?